# Accessing core data entity from another view controller and adding further attributes

Tags: ios, swift, entity-framework, core-data, attributes

Is there a simple way of accessing the core data entity which I have created and am storing from another view controller?

Currently I have a Map view controller which has a map with various locations and associated details where the entity Places gets its attributes for lets say name, address etc. These objects are being created, stored and fetched in the Map view controller. Now I would like to pass that information on to a table view controller where I would want the entity attribute (lets say name) represented in a table form and then to add further attributes from further view controllers. As an example lets say I have a location called home in my map with xxxxxx address. then I would want to go and view home in my tableview and its associated attributes as well as add a photo of my home. Is there some way of easily accessing the core data from these other view controllers? and creating attributes from new view controllers to add to the entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass your items onto the second view controller. You can do this by passing your items manually or by overriding `prepare(for: sender:)`:

```
let viewController = secondViewController //instantiate it from the Storyboard or however else you want
viewController.items = items //items is an array containing your items
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

**if you're using segues:**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? MyViewController else { return }
    destination.items = items //items is an array containing your items
}
```

In both cases, remember to place the above code in your first view controller.